# How to add notch to TabBar to place FloatingActionButton in it

Tags: dart, flutter, navigationbar, tabview, floating-action-button

I would like to create a notch inside the TabBar to place the FloatingActionBottom in it but I don't know how to do that.

I found nothing in the documentations or on the internet.

[image: FloatingActionButton on BottomNavigationBar]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Bottom App Bar for this kind of User Interface
The hasNotch property of the BottomAppBar must be true.

This would get you what I am upto

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Bottom App Bar')),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: 
      FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: const Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {},),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      hasNotch: true,
      child: new Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {},),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {},),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Try implementing this revised version of the code. The FAB should persist across the three tabs

```
class BarTab extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
          ],
        ),
        title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.audio),
          Icon(Icons.play),
          Icon(Icons.maps),
        ],
      ),

 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
 onpressed:(){},
 child: Icon(Icons.add),
),
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
bottomNavigationBar:BottomAppBar(
 color:Colors.blue,
 hasNotch: true,
 child:Container(
height:50.0
child:Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
      onPressed: (){})
  ]
)
)

    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: I get it, you want something here and there but you have to show some effort. You just cannot post screenshots and tell people to write the code for you

Comment: I just want a hint, not anyone to write a code for me. I apologize if I expressed myself wrongly.

Comment: Okay. What do you mean when you said in the other guys post that _I just checked your code and it is not a TabView nor on top of the screen_      . How exactly is each placement you need since your screenshot is misleading. It gives the impression you already have a tab view but do not know how to put the docked FAB

Comment: Sorry if I expressed myself wrongly. I think the matter is that I try to put a TabBar inside the BottomAppBar to create a notch in the TabBar.

Comment: I just noticed that I said TabView instead of TabBar. Sorry I was really confused yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

2020 solution:

hasNotch property is no more in BottomAppBar, however, you can do this in Scaffold

```
 bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(), //this is what creates the notch 
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: SizedBox(
      height: height * 0.1,
      width: width,
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    width: 80.0,
    height: 80.0,
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Icon(
        Icons.add,
        size: 25.0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked
```

output :

[image]